# How to create this layer on my app to teach users?

Tags: java, android

I want create layer like below to teach users if you click on some position you can use some service.sorry I don't know what is it that I search on the web

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easily achieved with ShowcaseView: https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView